# Enterprise Keyword not updating in SharePoint 2010 using client object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, managed-metadata

Tried the following, it didn't give any error, but that column wouldn't update, while the Title did. please help me to resolve this problem

```
using (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext clientcontext = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("siteUrl"))
            {
                try
                {
                    List taxonomyList = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TaxonomyHiddenList");
                    // List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("tester");


                    CamlQuery camlQueryForTerm = new CamlQuery();
                    camlQueryForTerm.ViewXml = @"<View>
                  <Query>
                    <Where>
                      <Eq>
                        <FieldRef Name='Term'/>
                        <Value Type='Text'>abc</Value>
                      </Eq>
                    </Where>
                  </Query>
                </View>";


                    ListItemCollection termItems = taxonomyList.GetItems(camlQueryForTerm);
                    //  ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQueryForItem);


                    clientcontext.Load(termItems);
                    //  clientContext.Load(listItems);
                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

                    ListItem termItem = termItems[0];
                    //  ListItem item = listItems[0];

                    string termValue = termItem["ID"] + ";#" + termItem["Term"] + "|" + termItem["IdForTerm"];

                    List oList = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Metadata");

                    ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                    ListItem oListItem = oList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
                    oListItem["Title"] = "My First Item!";

                    oListItem["TaxKeyword"] = termValue;

                    oListItem.Update();
                    clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does the "termValue" parameter contain?

Comment: it contains term value like "46;#abc|74708ee0-16db-41d6-9443-72392b9fc739"

Comment: Did you ever found the solution for this?

Comment: yes i did it...

Comment: can you please share your inputs , I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
termValue = string.Format("{0}|{1}", term.Name, term.Id)
```

if there is more values, they should be separated with "`;`"